# How to use any model in a generic service in asp.net core blazor

Tags: c#, asp.net, blazor

I currently have a service and a blazor component in my blazor application which retrieves data from a database view and allows the user to update data.  Great! that's one page down. Now I have a bunch more to make that pretty much do the same thing. There is a model in my project for every database view.

My question is, do I have to create a service for every model?  Surely there's a way to have some sort of generic service where one could simply pass in the model for it to interact with.  I'm not really sure what I should be searching for to find help online. If someone could even just point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Code Setup

```
namespace AdministrationWebApplication.Models.Settings
{
    public partial class FlowSettingsView
    {
        public byte SettingId { get; set; }
        public string SettingName { get; set; }
        public object SettingValue { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace AdministrationWebApplication.Data
{
    public partial class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public virtual DbSet<FlowSettingsView> FlowSettingsView { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
          base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
          ...
        }
    ...
}

namespace AdministrationWebApplication.Services
{
    public class DataService
    {
        protected ApplicationDbContext _context { get; private set; }

        public DataService(ApplicationDbContext context)
        {
            _context = context;
        }
    }
}

namespace AdministrationWebApplication.Services
{
    public class SettingsService : DataService
    {
        public SettingsService(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context) {}

        public async Task<List<FlowSettingsView>> GetSettingsAsync()
        {
            return await _context.FlowSettingsView.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<int> UpdateSettingsAsync(List<FlowSettingsView> flowSettingsView)
        {
            _context.FlowSettingsView.UpdateRange(flowSettingsView);           
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

To have an idea of what I want to do, have a look at this version of the services class:

```
namespace AdministrationWebApplication.Services
{
    public class GenericDataService : DataService
    {
        AnyModel _anyModel;

        public GenericDataService(ApplicationDbContext context, AnyModel anyModel) : base(context) 
        {
         _anyModel = anyModel;
        }

        public async Task<List<AnyModel>> GetDataAsync()
        {
            return await _context.AnyModel.ToListAsync();
        }

        public async Task<int> UpdateAnyModelAsync(List<AnyModel> anyModel)
        {
            _context.AnyModel.UpdateRange(anyModel);           
            return await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of this

```
public async Task<List<AnyModel>> GetDataAsync()
{
    return await _context.AnyModel.ToListAsync();
}
```

you could use

```
public async Task<List<T>> GetDataAsync<T>()
{
    return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
}
```

(or move that`<T>` up to the class level).

Comment: Thank you sir! That almost done it for me.  To get this to work I needed to add  where T : class to the end of my method.  I avoided adding <T> to the class because then i'd have to pass in a model in Startup when I add my service under ConfigureServices.  My method looks like this now:
        public async Task<List<T>> GetDataAsync<T>() where T : class
        {
            return await _context.Set<T>().ToListAsync();
        }

Comment: Yes, that `where T : class` is needed, it bubbles up from the DbContext.

Comment: You _can_ register an 'open generic' but it depends on the usage patterns whether that is useful.